django template doesn't apply css
i want to use text-align = justify and reduce text width on a django template file but it doesn't work. static files and direction are working without problem but i can't do something to only this django element and i have no idea how to fix this. it's my css script :
#name1{

    text-align: justify;
    width: 20%;
}
#name2{

    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: lalezar;
}

and this my HTML script :
<html>
<header>
<body>
{% for item in post %}
<div id="post1">

  <a href="{% url 'page_detail' item.pk %}" id="name2"><h2 id="name1">{{item.title}}</h2></a>
  <h3>{{item.author}}</h3>

</div>

{% endfor %}

</body>
</header>
</html

i searched google but i didn't found anything.

So where do you include that CSS script?

Your last html tag is missing a >.

And your body is wrapped in the <header>?

@willeM_VanOnsem - it is works with  around . Browsers check it and repaired it. css is not applied for any other reason. Also the error in closed html also not the reason. You can copy the code and check it.


The HTML id attribute is used to specify a unique id for an HTML element
In your code you use ID css selector for multiple html elements, because you generate it through for loop.
I offer you to use css class instead of id:

// css file
.name1{
    ...
}

.name2{
    ...
}

and in template:
{# django template #}
{% for item in post %}
    <div id="post1">
        <a href="{% url 'page_detail' item.pk %}" class="name2">
            <h2 class="name1">
                {{item.title}}
            </h2>
        </a>
        <h3>
            {{item.author}}
        </h3>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

I hope you are not forget to check, if your css file loaded propertly:
{# don't forget to add link to css file in head of your html #}
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_file.css" />
</head>

